# If User.IsInRole with string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Im trying to build a custom validation where I check if the role contains a user. And I'm having problems with string array, what is best way to check if it contains a specific value?

```
    public string[] AuthRoles { get; set; }


    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        if (AuthRoles.Length > 0)
        {

            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

               RedirectToRoute(filterContext,
               new
               {
                   controller = "AdminLogin",
                   action = "AdminLogin"
               });

            }
            else
            {
                bool isAuthorized = filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(this.AuthRoles.??);

                if (!isAuthorized)
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("You are not authorized to view this page");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No Role Specified");
        }
```

How should I modify the check for User.IsInRole so it handles the array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
bool isAuthorized = 
    this.AuthRoles.Any(r => filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(r));
```

Edit: (Assuming that being member of any of the roles is enough to be authorized.)

Answer (score 8):

If you want the user to have all the roles in the `AuthRoles` at the same time, you should:

```
bool isAuthorized =
         Array.TrueForAll(AuthRoles, filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole);
```

If just being a member of at least one of the required roles is enough, use `Any`:

```
bool isAuthorized = AuthRoles.Any(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple linq expression:

```
bool isAuthorized = AuthRoles.All(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check each string

```
bool isAuthorized = false;

foreach(string role in AuthRoles)
{
  if(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(role))
    isAuthorized = true;
}
```

Comment: My solution only requires the user be member of one of the roles.  So it depends on what you are wanting.